# stun and turn configuration in kurento room api for android

Tags: android, webrtc, kurento, stun, turn

I have set up kurento media server along with stun and turn servers, added the configuration for the same in kms, I am using 
[this project](https://github.com/nubomedia-vtt/nubo-test) which is based on kurento room api for android.

However I haven't found a way to add the STUN and TURN server configuration in the kurento android room api. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

Solved.

The project depends on fi.vtt.nubomedia.webrtcpeerandroid library which is a project named [webrtcpeer-android](https://github.com/nubomedia-vtt/webrtcpeer-android), 
which in turn is a wrapper over org.java.webrtc, the library does not provide an api to add new ICE servers or change the existing ICE server.

Adding a method in NBMWebRTCPeer.java and recompiling the library solves the problem.

Comment: hi aditya can you provide me a method where i can configure it, made me to recompile it again.